# RichTextBox copy has an extra carriage return at the end

Tags: .net, winforms, format, richtextbox

For the first time ever, I'm investigating `RichTextBox` controls in C# Windows forms. I know I need this control in my app as `TextBox` is too simple for my needs.

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _19_richtextbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBoxHome_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == (char)(Keys.Return))
            {
                richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home:" + richTextBoxHome.Text + "\n");
                richTextBoxHome.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the moment I just want whatever is typed in one `RichTextBox` to be displayed on the other `RichTextBox` on hitting <kbd>Return</kbd>.

The issue is that everytime I hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, the data is being transfered to the other control but the first control is left with a carriage return before the cursor. This happens everytime I hit <kbd>Return</kbd>. Both the controls accept multiline input. How do I make it stop doing this?

---

i would like a way to make the "Home:" part in bold.

i have found very little info on this on my searches. the following are the only actual code that i could understand.

```
rtb1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi {\b hello} {\i World}}" ; 
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
```

---

im not sure how to proceed with this info. i just want the richtextbox to display "Home:" and "Away:" in bold and be able to handle URLs in text.

please advise what should i specify when searching this potic on google or any reference your could think of would be of great help.

thank you again for taking interest.

---

i have made progress on my issue and thought to share.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _19_richtextbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBoxHome_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                // richTextBoxChat.Rtf = @"{\rtf1 \b Home: \bO}" + @richTextBoxHome;

                // do not delete next 2 lines
                //string test = @"{\rtf1 \b Home: \b0";
                //test = test + richTextBoxHome.Rtf + "}";

                string chatBuffer = richTextBoxChat.Rtf;

                string buffer = @"{\rtf1";
                buffer = buffer + chatBuffer;

                buffer = buffer + @"\b Home:\b0";

                buffer = buffer + richTextBoxHome.Rtf + "}";


               // MessageBox.Show(buffer);
                richTextBoxChat.Rtf = buffer;
                //do not delete the following 2 lines
                //richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home:" + richTextBoxHome.Text);
                richTextBoxHome.Clear();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

just need to figure out how to get rid of the new lines/carriage returns in the text.

any tips most welcome.

thanks.

---

that did not workout so well. ended up using the below instead.

```
            this.richTextBoxChat.SelectionFont = new Font(this.richTextBoxChat.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home: ");
            this.richTextBoxChat.SelectionFont = new Font(this.richTextBoxChat.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
            richTextBoxChat.AppendText(richTextBoxHome.Text);
            richTextBoxChat.ScrollToCaret();
            richTextBoxHome.Clear();
```

Comment: Why do they accept multiline input if you don't want them to be able to hit return and it cause a newline?

Comment: Because you can't wrap text to a second line if it's not allowed to show a second line. The MultiLine property indicates whether to display more than one line of text, and text will not wrap unless MultiLine is true, regardless of the WordWrap property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the event to handled to prevent further processing of the return keydown event

Try this:

```
    private void richTextBoxHome_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)(Keys.Return))
        {
            richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home:" + richTextBoxHome.Text + "\n");
            richTextBoxHome.Clear();

            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        }
    }
```

**Edit**: added e.SuppressKeyPress = true; Cory Charlton pointed this out in his post.

**Edit**: also, as others have mentioned, use the KeyPress event handler, so if someone holds down enter/return the event is triggered over and over again.
an example of the usage is as follows:

```
    private void richTextBoxHome_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar.Equals((Char) Keys.Enter))
        {
            richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home:" + richTextBoxHome.Text + "\n");
            richTextBoxHome.Clear();

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: Also, there is a Property you can set on the RichTextBox to not allow MultiLine strings to be entered into the textbox. This does pose a problem when pasting content with multiple lines, it will only take the first line.

**For Bold words:**
You can change the SelectionFont of the RichTextBox to set it's font attributes:

```
    private readonly Font BoldSelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 9.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
    private readonly Font RegSelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 9.0f, FontStyle.Regular);

...
                richTextBoxChat.SelectionFont = BoldSelectionFont;
                richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home: ");
                richTextBoxChat.SelectionFont = RegSelectionFont;
                richTextBoxChat.AppendText(richTextBoxHome.Text + "\n");
...
```

Comment: maybe add a check for multiple keystrokes, such as Ctrl + Enter? Then the user can put in line breaks without causing the paste to occur.  maybe even reverse it to use Ctrl + Enter to trigger the paste.

Comment: @Jeremy Seghi: Good Point, I was just trying to make the OP aware of the issue that MultiLine can cause. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `KeyPress` instead of `KeyDown` and set `e.Handled=true`

Comment: For more information on KeyPress vs KeyDown:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326442

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the `KeyDown` event, write `e.Handled = true`.

Also, the best way to check what key was pressed is to write `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)`

Comment: thank you all of you! i find that as a beginner programmer a lot of the time is spent resolving these small issues and google can't help at times.

thanks you for all your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Handle and supress the key stroke:

```
    private void richTextBoxHome_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)(Keys.Return))
        {
            richTextBoxChat.AppendText("Home:" + richTextBoxHome.Text + "\n");
            richTextBoxHome.Clear();

            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 from me, I missed the SuppressKeyPress; not sure if e.Handled is needed anymore though. ;)